# Erro ao tentar instalar o aplicativo em flutter no celular físico

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estou com problemas para instalar o meu aplicativo no meu celular físico(Redmi 6 note PRO), eu já fiz alguns testes e o problema está no plugin de autenticação com o facebook, [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login), se eu retirar a mesma do meu projeto ele instala normalmente. Procurando na internet achei algumas soluções: trocar a API para 28, desabilitar a wifi ou dados moveis, verificar o proxy da rede, acontece que nem uma solucionou meu problema, e no caso da API eu já estou na 28.

Executando no terminal `flutter -v --bug-report run`, ele passa pelo gradlew normalmente e trava na hora da instalação/execução do aplicativo.

```
[   +1 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk... (completed in 43,4s)
[  +61 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s e87dd33d shell echo -n 68dff8b87b96398b2fbec0564a8c02ee1e20e879 >
/data/local/tmp/sky.br.com.sancon.app_gera.sha1
[ +483 ms] Redmi Note 6 Pro startApp
[   +5 ms] executing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s e87dd33d shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez
enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true br.com.sancon.app_gera/br.com.sancon.app_gera.MainActivity
[ +546 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=br.com.sancon.app_gera/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +4 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

ele fica aguardado e não sai disso, e no celular o app da uma piscada na tela mas logo fecha, se eu pedir para mostrar o relatório de execução do aplicativo ele me retorna isso:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
    at com.facebook.internal.BoltsMeasurementEventListener.open(BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java:54)
    at com.facebook.internal.BoltsMeasurementEventListener.getInstance(BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java:70)
    at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:313)
    at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:246)
    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider.onCreate(FacebookInitProvider.java:20)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1927)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1902)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6532)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6025)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:200)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1673)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.sancon.app_gera-3tnaw23GJtmgjgsVn442TQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.sancon.app_gera-3tnaw23GJtmgjgsVn442TQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/br.com.sancon.app_gera-3tnaw23GJtmgjgsVn442TQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 18 more
```

Também já tentei usar a versão 1.2.0 do plugin que não utiliza AndroidX, porem ela da conflito, estou tentando usar a versão mais atual(^2.0.1).

Meu nootbook e celular não tem bloqueio para o facebook ou algo do tipo na rede, e estou utilizando o Android Studio.

Comment: Se seu objetivo for utilizar o facebook apenas para autenticacao durante login na sua aplicacao, eu recomendaria utilizar o Google Firebase que alem de ser gratis e ilimitado é bem mais "reliable" do que uma lib do pub. Segue um tutorial que ensina a como integrar o facebook login no flutter com Firebase. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxZLHP0fGwk&t=103s

Comment: nesse momento eu não queria usar Firebase, mas pelo jeito não vou ter escolha kkk

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/308389)